# Глюк Jquery UI tab + yandex map

Tags: jquery, yandex-maps-api

обнаружил старнную ошибку с отображением yandex map на странице при ротации (изменения размера экрана)

Использую jquery UI tabs создаю 3 таба и 3 карт, каждая на своем табе.
Все работает нормально, на как только я меняю размер экрана и перехожу на другой таб, карта не отображается.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Соберите, пожалуйста, [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: http://youhobby.tilda.ws/

Answer (score 1):

Вы создаете карты в скрытых контейнерах с размером 0 на 0. Вызывайте [`map.container.fitToViewport`](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/map.Container-docpage/#method_detail__fitToViewport), после того как переключились на таб и контейнер карты показан на странице (`display` не `none`).